# i can see my game admob in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

I have a problem for insert admob in my game

This is my main activity MainActivity

```
package net.canarolab.puzzleroad; 



import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.media.AudioManager; 
import android.media.MediaPlayer; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.util.Log; 
import android.view.Menu; 
import android.view.MenuItem; 
import android.view.Window; 
import android.view.WindowManager; 
import android.widget.LinearLayout; 
import android.widget.Toast; 

import com.google.ads.AdRequest; 
import com.google.ads.AdSize; 
import com.google.ads.AdView; 

public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
private AdView adView; 
private MainView mainView; 
private final int MENU_SELECT_RESET=1,MENU_SELECT_CONTACT=2; 

// MUSICA 
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;// para musica de fondo (se declara aqui para que pueda 
// utilizarla todos nuestros metodos) 

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

// MUSICA 
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.merry); 
mediaPlayer.setLooping(true); 
mediaPlayer.setVolume(100,100); 
mediaPlayer.start(); 




//Apago la barra de título 
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
//Apago la barra de estado 
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 
Intent i = getIntent(); 
//Activity Quiero solo tapa 
//i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); 
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 
//View Establezca el 
mainView = new MainView(this); 
setContentView(mainView); 

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 


//PUBLICIDAD 
// Lookup R.layout.main 
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout); 

// Create the adView 
// Please replace MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID with your AdMob Publisher ID 
AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14e2f8fe3af5a6"); 

// Add the adView to it 
layout.addView(adView); 

// Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad 
AdRequest request = new AdRequest(); 
request.setTesting(true); 

adView.loadAd(request); 

//FIN PUBLICIDAD 
} 

@Override 
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present. 
// getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu); 
menu.add(0, MENU_SELECT_RESET, 0, "Reset"); 
menu.add(0, MENU_SELECT_CONTACT, 0, "Contact"); 
return true; 


} 

@Override 
protected void onResume() { 
mediaPlayer.start(); 

//Leí el recuento juego 
this.mainView.gameCount.read(); 
Log.d("", "read"); 
super.onResume(); 

} 

@Override 
protected void onPause() { 
mediaPlayer.pause(); 

//Escribo el recuento de juego. 
this.mainView.gameCount.save(); 
Log.d("", "save"); 

super.onPause(); 
//No voy a desaparecer en esta actitud no hay más. 
//finish(); 


} 

@Override 
protected void onDestroy() { 
mediaPlayer.stop(); 

super.onDestroy(); 
System.exit(0); 

} 

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
switch (item.getItemId()) { 
case MENU_SELECT_RESET: 
this.mainView.gameCount.reset(); 
Toast.makeText(this, "Has been reset．",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
return true; 
case MENU_SELECT_CONTACT: 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
intent.setType("text/plain"); 
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "idea"); 
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text of email"); 
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, 
new String[]{" trabajonacho33@gmail.com"}); 
startActivity(intent); 
} 
return false; 
}   

}
```

AND THIS IS MY XML activity_main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:launchMode="singleInstance" 
tools:context=".MainActivity" > 

<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/linearLayout" 
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" > 
</LinearLayout> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Only can see the banner but no my game
I think than can be a problem with setContentView

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should only call setContentView once.

What you want to do is to remove

```
mainView = new MainView(this); 
setContentView(mainView);
```

And configure a sibling element to @id/linearLayout in your layout XML that construct your MainView.